# PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

An event has a column `popularity` and many keywords. A keyword has a category and a name. I am trying to order events by their popularity, but then only return the most popular event from each keyword name with the category "taxonomy".

Here's my query:

```
Event
  .order(:popularity)
  .joins(:keywords)
  .where(keywords: {category: "taxonomy"})
  .group("keywords.name")
```

But I am getting below error:

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "events.id" must appear in the GROUP
>   BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Postgres version ? some are suggesting to use 9.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Event
  .order(:popularity)
  .joins(:keywords)
  .group('events.id') # <======
  .where(keywords: { category: 'taxonomy' })
  .group('keywords.name')
```