# ActiveRecord Error with PostgreSQL but not SQLite - GroupingError - column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

This ActiveRecord query works in SQLite:

```
SlotReq.group(:team_id)
```

In PostgreSQL, the same query gives this error "GroupingError - column slot_reqs.id must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function"

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116199/pggroupingerror-error-column-events-id-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause) I changed my query to:

```
SlotReq.select("slot_reqs.team_id").group("slot_reqs.team_id")
```

and it works as expected.

I would like to know if I'm doing it right and why does this work?

Comment: is team_id unique in the table? Which version of PostgreSQL are you using?

Comment: This answer may make things clear. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18061451/7573791

Comment: team_id is a foreign key in the table, so not unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are doing it right, although you could also use:

```
SlotReq.select(:team_id).group(:team_id)
```

What happens is that PG (among other DB's) needs that all column names in `SELECT` must be either aggregated or used in `GROUP BY` clause; this is because, if any unagreggated column is omitted, it could lead to indeterminate behavior (i.e. What value should be used in that column?)

So, by specifying in `select` just the column you want to `group`, you don't omit any column; on the other hand, using `group` without`select`, is equivalent to doing `SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY column`, which brings all columns but only one being specified on `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Replaced my query with yours using symbols. Looks much better to me. Thanks for your explanation.