# Postgres - Group by multiple columns, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a table named property_audit_version_histories.
i am fetching the records using the following code

```
@version_logs = PropertyAuditVersionHistory
                    .includes(:property_audit_version, :user)
                    .where(property_audit_version_id: params[:id])
```

The result contain 3 records, 2 of which have the same action and user_id
Now i need to group the records using the columns action, user_id

I am getting the following error when i try to group the records

```
@version_logs = PropertyAuditVersionHistory
                        .includes(:property_audit_version, :user)
                        .where(property_audit_version_id: params[:id])
                        .group("action, user_id")

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "property_audit_version_histories.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

Based on the thread [PG::GroupingError: ERROR: column "events.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116199/pggroupingerror-error-column-events-id-must-appear-in-the-group-by-clause?rq=1) i have modified the code as follows

```
@version_logs = PropertyAuditVersionHistory
                    .includes(:property_audit_version, :user)
                    .group("property_audit_version_histories.id")
                    .where(property_audit_version_id: params[:id])
                    .group("action, user_id")
```

Now the error is gone but still the result is having 3 records. After grouping i expect only 2 records. 
[image]

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: could you add the resulting query from logs?

Comment: SELECT "property_audit_version_histories".* FROM "property_audit_version_histories" WHERE "property_audit_version_histories"."property_audit_version_id" = $1 GROUP BY property_audit_version_histories.id, action, user_id  [["property_audit_version_id", 44]]

Answer (score 0):

You cant select all columns like mysql in postgresql when doing aggregrates.

So I guess this should work.

```
@version_logs = PropertyAuditVersionHistory    
                    .where(property_audit_version_id: params[:id])
                    .group("action", "user_id", "property_audit_version_id")
                    .select("user_id", "action", "property_audit_version_id")
```

I dont know how is your model but this should work. If you need more fields let me know

Comment: The problem is that i need to include property_audit_version_histories.created_at in the select condition. Once i add that an error appears saying that created_at should be added in the group condition also. After adding that there will be 3 records.

Comment: Could you try with the new version (updated answer) ? It should work. @version_logs.each { |vl| vl.property_audit_version.created_at }

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is specify which columns you want with

```
  .select("user_id")
```

But for the columns you know will be the same use `max(columnName) as columnName`

for example:

```
.select("MAX(user_id) as user_id, action")
```

Make sure you are 100% sure that those columns will be the same value after grouping.